# How to modify my macOS GUI app's menu depending on the option key press?

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

I create my own menu item for my macOS GUI app. Here's a pseudo-code:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
                
        Window("My macOS App",
               id: "idMyApp")
        {

            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("My Menu")
            {
                Button(action: {

                })
                {
                    Text("Shown always")
                }

                Button(action: {
                    
                })
                {
                    Text("Shown only if the Option key is pressed")
                }

            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

I want to achieve similar functionality to the Finder window. Say, if you open the `Go` menu and press the `⌥` key, the menu changes dynamically with additional options:

[image]

Can I do the same with SwiftUI?